# js. splice returns removed item?

Tags: javascript

I am having problem of understanding splice and I want to have help.

Please check the jsfiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/fantill/TbpWf/1/

```
value = "c, a, b"
value = value.split(',').splice(1, 1).join(',')
alert(value);
```

the value is supposed have return `'c, b'`.

However, it returns `'a'`;

What is wrong with this method?

Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Yes, `splice` returns the removed items, and the output is supposed to be `a` because that's what you removed. Where's the problem?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`.splice` *does* return the removed item.  However, it also manipulates the array internally.  This prevents you from chaining anything to `.splice`; you must do two separate calls:

```
value = value.split(',');
value.splice(1, 1);
console.log(value.join(','));
```

If you do `value = value.splice(...)`, `value` is overridden, and the array is lost!

Answer (score 10):

`.splice` is in-place, so just remove the `value =` and it'll modify the array like you'd expect:

```
> var value = "c, a, b";
> value = value.split(', ');
["c", "a", "b"]
> value.splice(1, 1);
["a"]
> value
["c", "b"]
```

Answer (score 8):

```
var a = ["1","2","3"]
a.splice(1,1) && a
a=["1","3"]
```

Comment: Although this may answer the question, some comments and/or explanation would be nice. That will help other users as well.

Comment: it's solutions like this one that remind me I have no idea how javascript actually works.

Comment: the result of `splice` will always be an array, and even an empty array will be evaluated as `true`. in javascript, and in most languages, `true` `&&` `anything` will always equal that thing, in this case the array that has been spliced.

Answer (score 3):

If you find `splice`'s return behavior annoying, as many do, and have to use it often enough within one program, you might consider adding one of the following two custom prototype functions to use instead.

There is the popular `spliced` option, which behaves as you expected `splice` to behave in your question.

```js
Array.prototype.spliced = function() {
    Array.prototype.splice.apply(this, arguments);
    return this;
}

value = "c, a, b";
value = value.split(',').spliced(1, 1).join(',');
console.log(JSON.stringify(value));
```

The other option is one that can be used in a variety of situations. It will perform any array function specified using the parameters after it, and will always return the array.

```js
Array.prototype.arrEval = function() {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    Array.prototype[args.shift()].apply(this, args);
    return this;
}

// splice example
value = "c, a, b";
value = value.split(', ').arrEval('splice', 1, 1).join(', ');
console.log(JSON.stringify(value));

// push example
value = value.split(', ').arrEval('push', 'a').join(', ');
console.log(JSON.stringify(value));

// unshift example
value = value.split(', ').arrEval('unshift', 'f', 'e', 'd').reverse().join(', ');
console.log(JSON.stringify(value));
```

---

Doing the same thing in one line without a custom function is also possible with inline variable assignment, for the truly bold.

```js
value = "c, a, b"
value = ((arr = value.split(',')).splice(1, 1), arr.join(','))
alert(value);
```