# setState is not called

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to make a table in which entries can be added and removed from a table to the list and vice versa.

It seems the error occurs in the setState method since the log in the callback isn't executed.

Here is my component:

```
Array.prototype.invertedSplice = function() {
    Array.prototype.splice.apply(this, arguments);
    return this;
};
class SomeName extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      table: {
        country: ["United States", "Canada", "Great Britain"],
        medals: [127, 63, 67]
      },
      dropdown: {
        country: [],
        medals: []
      }
    };
    this.TableView = this.TableView.bind(this);
    this.ListView = this.ListView.bind(this);
  }
  ListView() {
    let list = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < this.state.dropdown.country.length; i++) {
      list.push(<div class="listitem">
        {this.state.dropdown.country[i]}
        <button key={this.state.dropdown.country[i]} onClick={this.addEntry.bind(this, i)}><svg/></button>
      </div>);
    }
    return(list);
  }
  TableView() {
    let table = [];
    console.log("tableview called");
    for (let i = 0; i < this.state.table.country.length; i++) {
      table.push(
        <tr>
          <td>{this.state.table.country[i]}</td>
          <td>{this.state.table.medals[i]}</td>
          <td key={this.state.table.country[i]}><button onClick={this.removeEntry.bind(this, i)}><svg width="70" height="5">
            <line x1="3" y1="2.5" x2="67" y2="2.5" />
            </svg></button></td>
        </tr>
      );
    }
    return(table);
  }

  addEntry (entryIndex) {
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      table: {
        country: 
         this.state.table.country.splice(entryIndex, 0, this.state.dropdown.country[entryIndex]),
        medals: this.state.table.medals.splice(entryIndex, 0, this.state.dropdown.medals[entryIndex])
      },
      dropdown: {
        country: this.state.dropdown.country.invertedSplice(this.state.dropdown.country[entryIndex], 1),
        medals: this.state.dropdown.medals.invertedSplice(this.state.dropdown.medals[entryIndex], 1)
      }
    }));
  }

  removeEntry (entryIndex) {
    console.log("removeEntry called")
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      table: {
        country: this.state.table.country.invertedSplice(this.state.table.country[entryIndex], 1),
        medals: this.state.table.medals.invertedSplice(this.state.table.medals[entryIndex], 1)
      },
      dropdown: {
        country: 
          this.state.dropdown.country.concat(this.state.table.country.splice(entryIndex, 1)),
        medals: this.state.dropdown.medals.concat(this.state.dropdown.medals.splice(entryIndex, 1))
      }
    }), () => console.log("the state was set"));
  }

  render() {
    console.log("render called");
    return(
      <div>
        <div className="list">
          <this.ListView />
        </div>
        <div className="table">
          <table>
            <caption>Example!</caption>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <th>Country</th>
                <th>Medals</th>
              </tr>
              <this.TableView />
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

This is my first question so feel free to give me any tips on my etiquette or code quality.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: it merely says

The above error occurred in the <SomeName> component:
    in SomeName (at src/index.js:122)

    in div (at src/index.js:121)

    in App (at src/index.js:128)

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.

Visit (link)react-error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.

Comment: I've never seen `<this.ListView />` this syntax before - what happens if you change it to `{this.ListView()}` and `{this.TableView()}`?

Comment: The same thing happens. I guess it's interchangeable.
This syntax is shown in the react docs:
https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html

Comment: You have a typo in `country: this.state.dropdown.country.spliced(` it should be `splice`

Comment: I defined a function below it called spliced that returns the array without the spliced item, so instead of splice returning one item that is removed it returnes the whole array without that one item. inspired by the 4th(last) answer on this post: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15082553/js-splice-returns-removed-item

It works by taking this which is the first argument passed to spliced (the array) and the argument which is the second argument (the 1).

Comment: it's trying to call it on `country` though, I don't think the function exists there

Comment: Oh so you suppose it's not in scope?
maybe i should try binding it in the constructor too...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to use the `spliced` function from https://stackoverflow.com/a/55211138/2763250, you will want to move that out of the component as you are just adding a function to the `Array` prototype. `country` is an array, and `spliced()` didn't exist on the Array prototype so it threw an error. You just had a `spliced()` function in your component.

```js
Array.prototype.spliced = function() {
    Array.prototype.splice.apply(this, arguments);
    return this;
};

class SomeName extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      table: {
        country: ["United States", "Canada", "Great Britain"],
        medals: [127, 63, 67]
      },
      dropdown: {
        country: [],
        medals: []
      }
    };
    this.TableView = this.TableView.bind(this);
    this.ListView = this.ListView.bind(this);
  }
  ListView() {
    let list = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < this.state.dropdown.country.length; i++) {
      list.push(
        <div class="listitem">
          {this.state.dropdown.country[i]}
          <button
            key={this.state.dropdown.country[i]}
            onClick={this.addEntry.bind(this, i)}
          >
            <svg />
          </button>
        </div>
      );
    }
    return list;
  }
  TableView() {
    let table = [];
    console.log("tableview called");
    for (let i = 0; i < this.state.table.country.length; i++) {
      table.push(
        <tr>
          <td>{this.state.table.country[i]}</td>
          <td>{this.state.table.medals[i]}</td>
          <td key={this.state.table.country[i]}>
            <button onClick={this.removeEntry.bind(this, i)}>
              <svg width="70" height="5">
                <line x1="3" y1="2.5" x2="67" y2="2.5" />
              </svg>
            </button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      );
    }
    return table;
  }

  addEntry(entryIndex) {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      table: {
        country: this.state.table.country.splice(
          entryIndex,
          0,
          this.state.dropdown.country[entryIndex]
        ),
        medals: this.state.table.medals.splice(
          entryIndex,
          0,
          this.state.dropdown.medals[entryIndex]
        )
      },
      dropdown: {
        country: this.state.dropdown.country.spliced(
          this.state.dropdown.country[entryIndex],
          1
        ),
        medals: this.state.dropdown.medals.spliced(
          this.state.dropdown.medals[entryIndex],
          1
        )
      }
    }));
  }

  removeEntry(entryIndex) {
    console.log("removeEntry called");
    this.setState(
      prevState => ({
        table: {
          country: this.state.table.country.spliced(
            this.state.table.country[entryIndex],
            1
          ),
          medals: this.state.table.medals.spliced(
            this.state.table.medals[entryIndex],
            1
          )
        },
        dropdown: {
          country: this.state.dropdown.country.concat(
            this.state.table.country.splice(entryIndex, 1)
          ),
          medals: this.state.dropdown.medals.concat(
            this.state.dropdown.medals.splice(entryIndex, 1)
          )
        }
      }),
      () => console.log("the state was set")
    );
  }
  
  render() {
    console.log("render called");
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="list">
          <this.ListView />
        </div>
        <div className="table">
          <table>
            <caption>Example!</caption>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <th>Country</th>
                <th>Medals</th>
              </tr>
              <this.TableView />
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<SomeName />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Ah my mistake. Though it still won't move the correct amount of items to the correct place.

Comment: I think that is not related to this question though

Comment: Ah true. I guess that concludes then. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Definitely ask another question if you attempt and get stuck!