# Return an array while modifying it does not work

Tags: javascript

Here is my confusion with return statements in Javascript:

I have a challenge on FreeCodeCamp.org to write a function that takes in 2 array's, and a position. I have to return array1 copied into array2 starting at the given position.

this code works:

```
function insertArrayAtPostion(arr1, arr2, postion) {
  arr2.splice(n,0,...arr1);
  return arr2;
}
```

However, I wonder why I can't just do this:

```
 function insertArrayAtPostion(arr1, arr2, postion) {
  return arr2.splice(n,0,...arr1);
}
```

Because I've been told JavaScript evaluates everything to the right before returning

Comment: because [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) doesn't return the array, it returns the deleted elements.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [js. splice returns removed item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15082553/js-splice-returns-removed-item)